# Undefined control sequence in basic pstricks work

Tags: pstricks

I am new to PStricks. My miktek library has pstricks package installed.

As I ran this code

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\psline(1,1)(5,1)(1,4)(1,1)
\pscircle[linestyle=dotted](3,2.5){2.5}
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray](2,2){1}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

it is giving me an error saying undefined control sequence.

Here is full version of error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.9 \psline(
1,1)(5,1)(1,4)(1,1)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.9 \psline(
1,1)(5,1)(1,4)(1,1)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

Comment: you need to use latex not pdflatex (also you could update pstricks as the current versions give a (slightly) better error message.

Comment: run the document with `xelatex`!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pdflatex` to compile  files with `pstricks` code, but as the .pdf  format (a subset of `postscript`) has  no computing engine  for the computations required by postscript, it has to outsource these computations. This is done through the `auto-pst-pdf` package.

It will work under the condition that you launch `pdflatex` with the `--enable-write18` switch under MiKTeX, or  `-shell-escape` under TeX Live or MacTeX.

I took the opportunity to slightly shorten and improve your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\pspolygon[linejoin = 1](1,1)(5,1)(1,4)
\pscircle[linestyle=dotted](3,2.5){2.5}
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray](2,2){1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is saying write 18 is not enabled? What should I do. I am using texmaker.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth: Go to the menu `Options > Configure Texmaker`, `TeX commands` tab, write in the `pdflatex` line: `pdflatex -synctex=1 --enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`.