# Using pstricks leads to the same undefined control sequence error

Tags: pstricks

While scrolling through the most popular questions i found this one:
[Nice scientific pictures show off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158668/nice-scientific-pictures-show-off). I tried compiling some of the scientific illustrations provided. Found that those that included pstricks gave me exactly the same error.

**For example:**

Compiling [Electric field due to 3 charges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/158930/revisions) gave me the following error:

[image]

After some digging, found some answers here: [Undefined control sequence in basic pstricks work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402974/undefined-control-sequence-in-basic-pstricks-work).

Went to the `Menu > Options > Configure Texmaker > TeX commands tab`, wrote in the pdflatex line: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`. Still i could not compile the file without getting the same error.

Also tried compiling with `LaTex+dvips+ps2pdf+Viewpdf` This time I got a pdf file of 24 pages, that included 24 instances of the animation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your actual question here? If it references an error during compilation, then it's a duplicate of [PSTricks error "Undefined control sequence <recently read> `\c@lor@to@ps`"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68870/5764). If it reference the fact that you want an animation (GIF) as output, then it's a duplicate of [How to convert `pstricks` animation to GIF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73545/5764) Either way, it seems to be a duplicate of something.

Comment: I didn't ask about the undefined control sequence error. I am aware it has already been answered. My question was why compiling with -shell-escape didn't work as it was supposed to. And if there is a way to produce the animation without using external software. So I dont think my question is an exact dublicate of another.

Answer (score 2):

You get 24 pages which can then be later converted to an animation with a program like `convert`. However, this one can be run with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>` and you'll get only one page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \psElectricfield[Q={[-1 3 0 PtoC][1 1 1][1 -1 -1]},linecolor=red]
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this convert program? Isnt there any way to produce animations with Tex?

Comment: @theohadoulis: See [How to convert `pstricks` animation to GIF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73545/5764)